# Is it safe to use an old 500w PSU (12v 4pin) with a new motherboard (12v 8pin)?

Tags: motherboard, power-supply

So I started a new build today, it's a budget build to replace a computer quickly.

Parts include...

- MB: [Gigabyte GA-H87-D3H](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4491&dl=#ov)
- CPU: i5-4430
- RAM: G.Skill 8G 1600 (single)
- HDD: Samsung 840 SSD

I was hoping to use my [old PSU](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817104934), but unfortunately it only has a 12V 4pin CPU connector, instead of the 8pin (ATX 12V 2X4) needed.

I will eventually go out and buy a new PSU, but I'm wondering if it would be safe to use the 4pin in the meantime?

Comment: This, is a good, clear and well worded question. +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be no problem with this, providing the PSU is powerful (which it should be). You may not be able to do much over clocking either. You may also run into issues under heavy CPU load and the machine potentially could just turn off!

Other people have reported this successfully too (http://www.overclock.net/t/1158071/4-pin-power-supply-on-8-pin-motherboard).

The question should be, which side you connect it too!

> You don't NEED to use all 8 pins for the EPS-12v. That's just in case
>   you wan't to feed the CPU more power if it needs it.
>
> If it has a 8-pin you can connect the 4 pins to one side of the
>   connector, depending on where your motherboard manual says to.

You may want to buy an adapter though which will 'update' it from 4 pin to 8 pin (recommended) or waiting until you get the new PSU but, that's just me being cautious!

Some times you can email the motherboard manufacturer though if you're worried about this before doing it!

Comment: I think I've figured it out. Reading the manual, I'm guessing the 4 pins marked "Only for 2x4-pin 12V", should be avoided, leaving the 4 other pins safe to plug into.